# Rotating the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

Is there a way to rotate the 3D Viewport as if rotating your head? I don't want to "rotate around the current selection" or around where I click, etc. Something like when you move the mouse in "Walk Navigation"

Unity has this in its Scene view when clicking RMB but I can't find the equivalent in Blender.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to bind "Walk Navigation" to a keyboard shortcut. Not ideal but works OK - just click to set the new view.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the 3D Viewport with Camera View (Numberpad 0), since the movement of a camera can be controlled through its Transforms (found in the N-Panel and Properties area > Object Properties tab) as well as the 3D Viewport's Tools.  If you don't want to move your rendering camera then another camera can be added (Add > Camera or Duplicate a selected camera with Shift-D) and changed to the [Active Camera](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/camera/introduction.html) (View > Camera > Set Active Object as Camera):

[image]

[image]

Since the Active Camera is used for both rendering and the 3D Viewport's Camera View you'll need to remember to make your rendering Camera the Active Camera again before rendering.  (There are exceptions, see Local Camera in the [Display & View Panels page of the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html) for more info.)

Comment: Thank you - this is a very creative answer! I was hoping there'd be a solution more like the natural viewport controls i.e. as I navigate around the scene, I can "turn my head" - I believe I'd have to move the camera to get this effect, with this solution.

Comment: Yes, you'd be moving a camera, which is why you'd probably make another camera for this.  Sorry it wasn't what you were looking for.